# Google Apps forward email from non-account address to an actual user

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, email-forwarding

In my Google Apps account I have only one user: `admin@example.com`. How can I configure Google Apps to forward emails for `info@example.com` to `admin@example.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend either of the ways listed by Ankur Mhatre. Creating another account is an admin headache (not to mention the cost) and the catch-all is not recommended by Google because it can lead to increased incidents of spam.

Instead you should either create a nickname for admin@ :

https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en

Or create a group with admin@ as a member:

https://support.google.com/a/topic/25838?hl=en&ref_topic=9197

Generally, if the mail sent to info@ only ever needs to go to admin@ use a nickname. If you have multiple users who need to receive mail from info@ use the groups.

Comment: Sorry it took me until now to respond. Yes - this is what I was looking for and is indeed the correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method, which also allows to forward to any email inside and outside of the organization, without creating an account:

- Apps > Google Apps > Gmail > Advanced settings
- Routing > Recipient address map
- Hover and click `CONFIGURE` on the right

The dialog is very simple, don't think it warrants a step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

**Way 1**

Create an account for info@domain.com and then forward all emails to admin@domain.com from settings of info@domain.com

**Way 2**

Make admin@domain.com as default address through your admin panel

You can refer this for creating default address (catch-all address)
https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, I created a catch-all. Not exactly what I wanted but close enough.

Comment: "not exactly what I wanted" means?

Comment: @Weehooey has the right answer - this would be too costly and inefficient.